# MVC AntiForgery Token error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am wondering how I should be handeling the following error/issue. I have a form that is getting submitted and on that form I am using AntiForgery token. The purpose of the form is to login to the site.

In the view I have:

```
<%: Html.AntiForgeryToken()%>
```

The controller reads:

```
[HttpPost]
[HandleError(ExceptionType = typeof(HttpAntiForgeryException),Master = "MasterLogin", View = "Login")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginPresentation model, string returnUrl)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

It works really well for the most part. Expect for the following case.

- I login to the site
- Logout of the site
- Clear my cache
- Attempt to authenticate

When I try to login I get the following error:
The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken_L1NTSS5NZW1iZXJzaGlwLlBvcnRhbA2" is not present.

How should I be dealing with this?

Comment: Your Logout is an HTTP Post action?  Also, when you Logout, does the app redirect directly to the Login view, or where does the user go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure that every request that is sent towards an action decorated with the `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute is made via HTTP POST and it comes from a form that has a hidden input containing the required token.
It can be generated using `Html.AntiForgeryToken()` and it looks like this:

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="some value" />
```

The token associated with the form is also stored as a cookie on the client machine, so when you submit the form, the ***ValidateAntiForgeryToken*** filter checks the following:

- The incoming request has a cookie called __RequestVerificationToken
- The incoming request has a Request.Form entry called __RequestVerificationToken
- These cookie and Request.Form values match

read more [here](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/).